# Flutter app IOS build TestFlight validation

Tags: ios, flutter, build, testflight

I'm working on a Flutter project. We added Notification service to it.
I'm trying to implement CI/CD using Github Actions.

iOS project configuration looks like

```
        00xxxxxxxxxxx00A449D1 /* Release */ = {
        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
        buildSettings = {
            CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
            CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "gnu++20";
            CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK = YES;
            CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS = YES;
            CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
            CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "Apple Development";
            CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
            CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)";
            DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = GUB29P472P;
            GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu11;
            GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE = YES;
            INFOPLIST_FILE = notificationservice/Info.plist;
            INFOPLIST_KEY_CFBundleDisplayName = notificationservice;
            INFOPLIST_KEY_NSHumanReadableCopyright = "";
            IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 16.2;
            LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "@executable_path/Frameworks",
                "@executable_path/../../Frameworks",
            );
            MARKETING_VERSION = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)";
            MTL_FAST_MATH = YES;
            PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.xxx.app.notificationservice;
            PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
            SKIP_INSTALL = YES;
            SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS = YES;
            SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0;
            TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2";
        };
        name = Release;
    };
```

notificationservice/Info.plist looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.xxx.app.notificationservice</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

GutHub actions flow steps looks like this

```
  - name: collect ipa artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: adhoc-ipa
      # Path to the release files
      path: build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
  - name: upload app to App Store Connect
    env:
      APP_STORE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.APP_STORE_API_KEY }}
      APP_STORE_ISSUER_ID: ${{ secrets.APP_STORE_ISSUER_ID }}
    run: |
      xcrun altool --upload-app -f "build/ios/ipa/Eyewa.ipa" -t ios --apiKey "$APP_STORE_API_KEY" --apiIssuer "$APP_STORE_ISSUER_ID"
```

Locally in Xcode I'm able archive, validate and publish release app.
But in GitHub actions I'm getting the error

```
2023-08-10 11:45:23.950 *** Error: ERROR: Asset validation failed (90057) The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: 1xxxxxxx-08b6-4b43-a0ae-4ac22fab72ea)
2023-08-10 11:45:23.951 *** Error: ERROR: Asset validation failed (90056) This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion (ID: c2e4c68b-1xxxxxxx-fd37d7617550)
2023-08-10 11:45:23.951 *** Error: ERROR: Asset validation failed (90360) Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required. (ID: 1xxxxxxx-4939-8206-dc2ac9e4e47a)
2023-08-10 11:45:23.952 *** Error: ERROR: Asset validation failed (90360) Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required. (ID: 1xxxxxxx-a71b-af3d38340594)
2023-08-10 11:45:23.964  INFO: Show Progress: Upload failed.
Asset validation failed
The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: 1xxxxxxx-a0ae-4ac22fab72ea)
2023-08-10 11:45:23.964  INFO: 
=============
UPLOAD FAILED with 4 errors.
=============
2023-08-10 11:45:23.966 *** Error: Error uploading 'build/ios/ipa/xxx.ipa'.
2023-08-10 11:45:23.966 *** Error: Asset validation failed The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: 1xxxxxxx-08b6-4b43-a0ae-4ac22fab72ea) (90057)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Asset validation failed";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: 1xxxxxxx-08b6-4b43-a0ae-4ac22fab72ea)";
    "original_server_error" =     {
        code = "STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90057";
        detail = "The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring";
        id = "1xxxxxxx-4b43-a0ae-4ac22fab72ea";
        status = 409;
        title = "Asset validation failed";
    };
}
2023-08-10 11:45:23.966 *** Error: Asset validation failed This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion (ID: 1xxxxxxx-62fb-4bc6-80a3-fd37d7617550) (90056)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Asset validation failed";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion (ID: 1xxxxxxx-62fb-4bc6-80a3-fd37d7617550)";
    "original_server_error" =     {
        code = "STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90056";
        detail = "This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion";
        id = "1xxxxxxx-62fb-4bc6-80a3-fd37d7617550";
        status = 409;
        title = "Asset validation failed";
    };
}
2023-08-10 11:45:23.967 *** Error: Asset validation failed Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required. (ID: 1573c61d-a2d8-4939-8206-dc2ac9e4e47a) (90360)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Asset validation failed";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required. (ID: 1573c61d-a2d8-4939-8206-dc2ac9e4e47a)";
    "original_server_error" =     {
        code = "STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90360";
        detail = "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required.";
        id = "1xxxxxxx-a2d8-4939-8206-dc2ac9e4e47a";
        status = 409;
        title = "Asset validation failed";
    };
}
2023-08-10 11:45:23.967 *** Error: Asset validation failed Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required. (ID: 1xxxxxxx-0519-4e31-a71b-af3d38340594) (90360)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Asset validation failed";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required. (ID: 1xxxxxxx-0519-4e31-a71b-af3d38340594)";
    "original_server_error" =     {
        code = "STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90360";
        detail = "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/notificationservice.appex is required.";
        id = "1xxxxxxx-0519-4e31-a71b-af3d38340594";
        status = 409;
        title = "Asset validation failed";
    };
}
```

From the configuration you can see that both **CFBundleVersion** and **CFBundleShortVersionString** are set

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

Also If I'm using static text values in **CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION** and **MARKETING_VERSION** it actually works.

I'm can't find the root cause and figure out the solution. Appreciate any input or help